# How to Perform groupBy in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
auto = sc.textFile("temp/auto_data.csv")
auto = auto.map(lambda x: x.split(","))
header = auto.first()
autoData = auto.filter(lambda a: a!=header)
```

now I have data in autoData

```
[[u'', u'ETZ', u'AS1', u'CUT000021', u'THE TU-WHEEL SPARES', u'DIBRUGARH', u'201505', u'LCK   ', u'2WH   ', u'KIT', u'KT-2069CZ', u'18', u'8484'], [u'', u'ETZ', u'AS1', u'CUT000021', u'THE TU-WHEEL SPARES', u'DIBRUGARH', u'201505', u'LCK   ', u'2WH   ', u'KIT', u'KT-2069SZ', u'9', u'5211']]
```

now I want to perform `groupBy()` on 2nd and 12th(last) values. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`groupBy` takes as an argument a function that generates keys so you can do something like this:

```
autoData.groupBy(lambda row: (row[2], row[12]))
```

**Edit**:

Regarding task [you've described in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807544/how-to-perform-groupby-in-pyspark/31808503?noredirect=1#comment51697745_31808503). `groupBy` only gathers data in groups but it doesn't aggregate it.

```
from operator import add

def int_or_zero(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return 0

autoData.map(lambda row: (row[2], int_or_zero(row[12]))).reduceByKey(add)
```

**Highly inefficient** version using `groupBy` could look like this:

```
(autoData.map(lambda row: (row[2], int_or_zero(row[12])))
     .groupByKey()
     .mapValues(sum))
```

Comment: if i used     autoData.groupBy(lambda row: (row[2], int(row[12]))) now second value is int ,but it give me the same result as previous . i want sum of last column according to second using groupBy(). i'm already archive this result using map-reduce. but i want to use this function.